# Intercept USSD events on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ussd

Windows phone7 does not support phase 2 communication using USSD.  Is there a way to intercept an outgoing USSD request on a Windows Phone 7 device in order to route to an application to handle the request instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APIs for such low level operations --- even more so when they are related to the cellular interface --- are not available.

If we take into account that more innocent things are not allowed in WP7, I think that the USSD interception has little chance of being available in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Only Microsoft Partners or OEMs have access to native API which is basically something much like Windows CE/Windows Mobile. There are functions that can receive USSD but none that can prevent default handling of the messages (namely: displaying popup with the message).